# How can I check if a string is ONLY one char and is either * or ? or _ via Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
var t = Console.ReadLine();
bool inputIsOnlyOneCharacterAndIsEitherAsteriskOrUnderScoreOrQuestionMark = ....
```

How can I check if variable t is only one character and it is either '*' or '_' or '?' by using the Regex?

Comment: I hope that variable name for your result isn't used in your code anywhere.

Comment: Couldn't help but laugh at the variable name. ^_^

Comment: Good if I made yo laugh Ryan :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this Regular Expression

```
/^[*_?]{1}$/
```

`^` - Instructs the RegEx engine to match from the beginning of the string

`[*_?]` - Instructs the RegEx engine to match any of the characters inside the `[]`

`{1}` - Match only one character. **Note :** This would be redundant in this case. So, you can ignore this.

`$` - Make sure that end of string is reached.

Comment: `{1}` is **always** redundant.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks :) Added a note in the answer

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, if you don't have to use regex, you don't need it here:

```
char[] allowed = new[]{ '?', '_', '*' };
bool inputIsOnlyOneCharacterAndIsEitherAsteriskOrUnderScoreOrQuestionMark = 
   t.Length == 1 && allowed.Contains(t[0]);
```

Comment: I suppose we could change it to be `string` instead of `char` and skip the length check? (EDIT: that is, just check for equality with the entries)

Comment: That variable name O_O.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `string[] allowed = new[]{ "?", "_", "*" }; bool inputIsOnlyOneCharacterAndIsEitherAsteriskOrUnderScoreOrQuestionMark = allowed.Contains(t);` EDIT: Also, for your question, yeah, `t` is a string coming from `Console.ReadLine`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Yes, you can. But OP wanted just chars. He also wanted to ensure that the string's length is 1 and a length-check is the most efficient pre-check.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well, if it's length is more than 1, it fails, if it's only 1, then the first character is the same as the full length of the string. In retrospect, the length check _does_ skip the iteration/checks of the array entries when we know they will fail. This also has the benefit of being more declarative to the intent ("I want it to be 1 length, and the first (only?) character being one of these" and the code matches that intent exactly whereas mine obscures the meaning/intent.

Comment: Also you could do `bool isOK = t.Length == 1 && "*_?".Contains(t[0]);` since strings implement `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: yes, that's also possible. It's just a matter of readability. I find the array more maintainable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Agreed, but I was thinking more of `var allowed = "*_?";` versus `var allowed = new[]{ '?', '_', '*' };`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have or need to use a regex, I'd go with a way more readable implementation:

```
var t = Console.ReadLine();
switch(t)
{
    case "*":
    case "?":
    case "_": { /* match! */ } break;
    default: { /* not a match !*/ } break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use set of characters (`[..]`) with `^` (match at the start) and `$` (match at the end):

```
"^[*_?]$"
```

---

```
Regex.IsMatch("_", "^[*_?]$") // True
Regex.IsMatch("_", "^[*_?]$") // True
Regex.IsMatch("?", "^[*_?]$") // True
Regex.IsMatch("!", "^[*_?]$") // False
```